# Set fix index to each Image

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

So I have a problem. This app allows users to upload images to Cloud Firestore and it retrieves them and shows them into the view. Each image should become an index, that is fix to the image. My code doesn't do that. It creates indexes for the images, but when an image is being deleted, the indexes change, so for example if image 3 had the index 4, when I delete image 2 that had index 3, the index of the other images changes.
Any Suggestions?

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore
import simd

struct WardrobeView: View {
    
    @State private var showButton = false
    @State private var selectedImgBtn: UIImage?
    @State private var retrievedImgBtn: [UIImage] = []
    @State var isPickerShowing = false
    @State var isImageSelected = false
    @State var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @State var retrievedImages = [UIImage]()
    @State private var selection = "Select"
    @State var changeCategory = 0
    @State var title = "Title"
    @State var warning = ""
    let categories = ["Select", "Hoodie", "T-Shirt", "Pants", "Shoes"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [
                    GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150))
                ], spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(retrievedImages.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        VStack {
                            Image(uiImage: retrievedImages[index])
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                                .clipped()
                                .overlay(
                                    Button(action: {
                                        // handle button tap
                                        deletePhoto(at: index)
                                    }) {
                                        Image(systemName: "trash.fill")
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                                    }
                                    .padding(8)
                                    .background(Color.red.opacity(0.8))
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 2)
                                    .offset(x: 0, y: 0),
                                    alignment: .topTrailing
                                )
                            Text("Image \(index)")
                                .padding(.top, 5)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    changeCategory += 1
                    if (changeCategory == 4) {
                        changeCategory = 0
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
                        .font(.system(size: 40.0))
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            }
            
            Divider()
            
            HStack {
                Picker("Select a category:", selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(categories, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
            }
            HStack {
                
                if isImageSelected == false {
                    Button{
                        isPickerShowing = true
                    } label: {
                        Text("Select Photo")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .font(.system(size: 18).bold())
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                            )
                    }
                    .background(Color.blue) // If you have this
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                } else {
                    
                    Button {
                        if(selection != "Select") {
                            uploadPhoto()
                            isImageSelected = false
                            warning = ""
                            
                            
                            switch categories {
                            case ["Hoodie"]:
                                changeCategory = 0
                            case ["T-Shirt"]:
                                changeCategory = 1
                            case ["Pants"]:
                                changeCategory = 2
                            case ["Shoes"]:
                                changeCategory = 3
                            default:
                                0
                            }
                            
                            switch changeCategory {
                            case 0:
                                retrievePhotos(category: "Hoodie")
                                title = "Hoodies"
                            case 1:
                                retrievePhotos(category: "T-Shirt")
                                title = "T-Shirts"
                            case 2:
                                retrievePhotos(category: "Pants")
                                title = "Pants"
                            case 3:
                                retrievePhotos(category: "Shoes")
                                title = "Shoes"
                            default:
                                0
                            }
                        } else {
                            warning = "Please select a category!"
                        }
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("Upload Photo")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .font(.system(size: 18).bold())
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                            )
                    }
                    .background(Color.blue) // If you have this
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    Button {
                        isImageSelected = false
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "x.square.fill").foregroundColor(.red)
                            .font(.system(size: 35.0))
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                }
                
            }
            .padding()
            
            Divider()
            
            HStack {
                Text(warning).foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPickerShowing, onDismiss: nil) {
            ImagePicker(selectedImage: $selectedImage, isPickerShowing: $isPickerShowing, isImageSelected: $isImageSelected)
        }
        .onChange(of: changeCategory) { newValue in
            switch newValue {
            case 0:
                retrievePhotos(category: "Hoodie")
                title = "Hoodies"
            case 1:
                retrievePhotos(category: "T-Shirt")
                title = "T-Shirts"
            case 2:
                retrievePhotos(category: "Pants")
                title = "Pants"
            case 3:
                retrievePhotos(category: "Shoes")
                title = "Shoes"
            default:
                0
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            retrievePhotos(category: "Hoodie")
            title = "Hoodies"
        }
        .padding(.top, 75)
        .overlay {
            ZStack {
                Color.clear
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    .blur(radius: 10)
                
                Text(title)
                    .font(.largeTitle.weight(.bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
            }
            .frame(height: 70)
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        }
    }
    
    func uploadPhoto() {
        
        if selection != "Select" {
            guard selectedImage != nil else {
                return
            }
            
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
            
            let imageData = selectedImage!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
            
            guard imageData != nil else {
                return
            }
            
            let hoodieNumber = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "counter")
            let tshirtNumber = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "tshirt")
            let pantsNumber = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "pants")
            let shoesNumber = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "shoes")
            
            var selectionInfo = 0
            
            let path = "\(selection)/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
            let fileRef = storageRef.child(path)
            
            let uploadTask = fileRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
                if error == nil && metadata != nil {
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()
                    switch selection {
                    case "Hoodie":
                        selectionInfo = hoodieNumber
                    case "T-Shirt":
                        selectionInfo = tshirtNumber
                    case "Pants":
                        selectionInfo = pantsNumber
                    case "Shoes":
                        selectionInfo = shoesNumber
                    default:
                        0
                    }
                    db.collection(selection).document(String(selectionInfo)).setData(["url":path]) { error in
                        switch selection {
                        case "Hoodie":
                            retrievePhotos(category: "Hoodie")
                            title = "Hoodies"
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "counter")
                        case "T-Shirt":
                            retrievePhotos(category: "T-Shirt")
                            title = "T-Shirts"
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(tshirtNumber + 1, forKey: "tshirt")
                        case "Pants":
                            retrievePhotos(category: "Pants")
                            title = "Pants"
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(pantsNumber + 1, forKey: "pants")
                        case "Shoes":
                            retrievePhotos(category: "Shoes")
                            title = "Shoes"
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(shoesNumber + 1, forKey: "shoes")
                        default:
                            0
                        }
                        selection = "Select"
                        print(hoodieNumber)
                        print(tshirtNumber)
                        print(pantsNumber)
                        print(shoesNumber)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func retrievePhotos(category: String) {
        self.retrievedImages = []
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection(category).getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if error == nil && snapshot != nil {
                
                var paths = [String]()
                
                for doc in snapshot!.documents {
                    paths.append(doc["url"] as! String)
                }
                for path in paths {
                    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
                    let fileRef = storageRef.child(path)
                    fileRef.getData(maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                        if error == nil && data != nil{
                            if let image =  UIImage(data: data!) {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    retrievedImages.append(image)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deletePhoto(at index: Int) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Hoodie").document(String(index)).delete() { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error removing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully removed!")
            }
        }
        print("Deleting image at index \(index)")
    }
    
    struct WardrobeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            WardrobeView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the index to be fixed to an image then you need to upload and store it together with the image. Off topic but I suggest you use an `enum` for your categories